# A question about general Marcinkiewicz interpolation theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lp-spaces, harmonic-analysis

The general Marcinkiewicz interpolation theorem states as following:

> If $T$ is a linear operator of weak type $(p_0,q_0)$ and of weak type
>   $(p_1,q_1)$ where $q_0\neq q_1$, then for each $\theta\in(0,1)$, $T$
>   is of type $(p,q)$, for $p$ and $q$ with $p\le q$ of the form
>   $$\frac{1}{p} = \frac{1-\theta}{p_0}+\frac{\theta}{p_1},\quad
> \frac{1}{q} = \frac{1-\theta}{q_0} + \frac{\theta}{q_1}.$$
>
> > When we say an operator $T$ is of **type $(p,q)$**, it means $||Tf||_q \leq C||f||_p$ for some $C$.
> >
> > When we say an operator $T$ is of **weak type $(p,q)$**, it means $||Tf||_{q,w} \le C||f||_p$ for some $C$. Here $||·||_{q,w}$ means the
> >     best constant $C$ such that $\lambda_f(t)\le \frac{C^q}{t^q}$ holds for all $t$ and $f$, where
> >     $\lambda$ is the distribution function.

On [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcinkiewicz_interpolation_theorem) it says this follows from the former (the restricted from where $p_0=p_1$ and $q_0 = q_1$) through an application of Hölder's inequality and a duality argument. But I do not understand it. Can someone say something more clear?

Comment: It seems I misunderstood the meaning... Anyway, does this theorem follow from the special case when $p_0=p_1$?

Comment: See https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/03/30/245c-notes-1-interpolation-of-lp-spaces/, starting from Theorem 27. He shows how to go from the special case to the general.

Comment: @GyuEunLee Thanks.